# Spinner moves downward in layout after selecting an item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a strange problem. I have added a `spinner` in a layout. when I select an item in `spinner`, `spinner` moves downward in layout causing vertical scroll in page. I don't want this happen because this causes button on my page to appear less on screen until scrolled.

As you can see in screenshots above the problem I am referring to."Add Gift to Bag" button is getting hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to specify the spinner's height,

Answer (score 0):

Can you please apply this on your spinner and check `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"` you can have it as a dialog as well by doing this `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`